# Verification on Proof for Measurable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Show that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone increasing on $E$, then $f$ is measurable.

Proof: Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and that $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone increasing on $E$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider $A = \{f > a\}$. Then $A$ can only be one of the following $\emptyset, E, [\inf A, \infty) \cap E,$ or $(\inf A, \infty) \cap E$. In either case $A$ is measurable, so $f$ must be measurable.

Is this proof correct? I am barely learning about measurable functions and I would like some confirmation from someone far more experienced than me.

Comment: Why $A = [\text{inf}A, \infty) \cap E$ implies  that $A$ is measurable ?

Comment: @Falcon The interval $[\inf A, \infty)$ is measurable. By assumption, $E$ is also measurable. Recall that the intersection of any countable measurable sets is still measurable.